# To send Multiple files to a method

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have to send all the files to a method.I tried the following code it throws file does not exist.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
for (int i = 1; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
    string fileName = Path.GetExtension(uploadfile.FileName);
    //String extension = Path.GetExtension(uploadfile.FileName);
    FileHidden.Value = uploadfile.ToString();
    string Files= FileHidden.Value ;
}

FileUpload(sBatchName, Files);
```

Comment: What line? And what is `FileHidden`?

Comment: Why don't you debug and see. And may be using `try-catch` as well?

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman in the hidden value i am storing file name